# nvarchar(max) slowing stored procedure

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

From yesterday, i'm facing a problem:when i call a stored proc from c#,it lasts >5 in, but when i execute it directly from SSMS (in the server machine) its lasts less than 30 seconds.

I have searched in forums and went trough this great article http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html but no result.

The script contained in my proc is retrieving 10 columns among them a column called "article" of type nvarchar(max).

When i remove the article column from my Select ,my proc executes quickly.

To further my logic, i have created a new stored proc retrieving just Primary Key Column and nvarchar(max) column.

I'm reproducing the same behaviour.Here is my new proc=MyNewProc(lasts >5 min when called from c# and 0 Secondes in the server from SSMS)

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE Student.GetStudents
  AS
  BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 -----------------
 SELECT StudentId,Article
 FROM Students
 WHERE Degree=1

 END
```

MyNewProc returns just 2500 rows.

Is that normal? How can i improve that.

SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(Article)) FROM Students WHERE Degree=1
 the result is 13885838

Comment: Please don't indent your questions like that. The system thinks indented text is to be highlighted as code.

Comment: Sounds like something is broken to me. How does the application connect to the SQL server? Sounds like a possible interconnect issue

Comment: when the Stored proc begins ,i see in the profiler:RPC Starting==>that means that it has begun to execute,right?

Comment: How big are the articles in average?

Comment: it's like Two pages of a doc file

Comment: What does this return? `SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(Article)) FROM Students WHERE Degree=1`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably transferring a lot of data over the network. That takes time.

Instead of returning `article` try returning `LEFT(article, 50)` to see if its an issue with the volume of data or not.

One thing to note is that SSMS will begin populating the results immediately while a C# application probably will not.

Comment: Every "article" would have to be pretty large (> 10 MB) to account for that kind of slowdown.  Maybe that's the case?

Comment: users do a copy paste from their doc files(average=two pages) to fill that field from an asp.net page

Comment: SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(Article)) FROM Students WHERE Degree=1 the result 13885838

Comment: @user594166  - How does your C# application connect to the SQL Server? Over the internet? That's about 362 Kbps if my maths is correct. (Note kilobits not kilobytes)

Comment: That's about 13MB of data to transfer

Comment: @Martin,yes it's over internet

Comment: @user Did you try returning LEFT(article, 50) with the same query?

Comment: @user594166 - Well it looks like the network connection isn't fast enough to sustain what you want it to do then.

Comment: @Joe Phillips when i execute the query with LEFT(article, 50) :9 seconds.What should i do.My task actually is to bring students with DegreeId=1 and filter them by them by Text typed by the user in my asp.net page.for example if the user types "Marketing Management" i should bring all students with DegreeId=1(with their articles)and eleminate  after those whom articles do not contain "Marketing" or "Management"

Comment: @user - Can't you host the database and web servers on the same network? But anyway even if the network connection was good it would be higly inefficient to bring all the records containing BLOBs back then eliminate the ones you don't need, you might want to look at making smaller requests and/or caching in your web application.

Comment: @Thanks Martin.What you mean look at making smaller requests and/or caching in your web application?bringing rows by groups (paging)

Answer (score -1):

In SSMS, go to the following: Tools -> Options

Then go to Query Execution -> SQL Server -> Advanced

From here, look at what check boxes are checked and if there is something that is checked, SSMS will use this automatically when you execute a sproc from inside of it but when you execute it from C# (or whatever client you're using) it won't be used.

I had this same issue and found out that I needed to include the following line at the top of my sproc and it worked perfectly:

SET ARITHABORT ON;

Comment: -1 The only difference this will make is that it is used as a plan cache key. You probably had a parameter sniffing issue. Since SQL Server 2005 if `ANSI_WARNINGS` is on then it acts as though `ARITHABORT` is on.

Comment: i went trough this article:http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html i have already tested SET ARITHABORT OFF not on,right? but no result,because it's ON by default in SSMS.FYI i'm in SQL Server 2008

Comment: ya, I wasn't sure if it would fix the problem or not. I just know that this is one of those tricky things that SSMS does behind the scenes by default which is different that executing the stored procedure from client code. Hope you find the answer!